# Efficient way to count view visits in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, view

I have an iOS app with about 50 views. I want to perform some operation after every 5th screen that the user visits. I know I can create a sort of global counter variable and update that on viewDidLoad of each view, and if count is 5, then perform that operation, and reset that counter variable. Is there a better, more efficient way of doing this? Also looking ahead, if I require to alter something, I would rather do it in a single file than all of my views. Would really appreciate some inputs on this.

Comment: Views, or view controllers? If it's view controllers, are you using a navigation controller and push segues? Do they all derive from the same view controller class (e.g. `UIViewController`)?

Comment: I'm using xibs and not storyboard. Yes I meant view controllers, and they all derive from UIViewController. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a singleton class to keep track of your counter logic, create a base class for all of your view controllers and then make your call to the counter singleton in the viewDidLoad of your base class.

I think something like this would work for you:

```
@interface ViewCountManager() 

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger viewCount;

@end

@implementation ViewCountManager

#define kOperateOnCount 5
+(ViewCountManager *)viewCountManager
{
    static ViewCountManager *viewCountManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        viewCountManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return viewCountManager;
}

-(BOOL)shouldPerformOperation
{
    BOOL retValue = NO;
if( self.viewCount == kOperateOnCount - 1 )
    {
        retValue = YES;
        self.viewCount = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        self.viewCount++;
    }
    return retValue;
}

@end


@implementation CountedViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];
    BOOL shouldPerform = [[ViewCountManager viewCountManager] shouldPerformOperation];
    [self performOperation];
}


@end
```